# I would like to replace string characters

Tags: javascript

Im trying to reverse a string using the following:

- Receive a character string as a parameter.
- Replace the vowels with the letter “V”.
- Reverse the string.
- Return the result

This is my code, but it does not seem to work.

```
function reverseString(str) {
    let charactere = str.split("").replace(/(a)|(i)|(e)/g, ‘V’);
    charactere.reverse().join(" ");

    return str;
}
```

Comment: yes, I added them to, still not passing the test

Answer (score 2):

You should perform the `replace` first, because it must be performed on a [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String).

[split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) returns an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), and an Array does **not** have a [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method.

Finally, if you return `str`, you are only returning the original input of the function. Here I save the result of reversing `charactere` to a new variable (`revStr`) and return it instead.

```js
function reverseString(str) {
    let charactere = str.replace(/[aei]/g, 'V').split("");
    const revStr = charactere.reverse().join("");
    return revStr;
}

console.log(reverseString('abcdefg')) // 'gfVdcbV'
```

Comment: thank you for the reply but it does not seem to ass the test, I can see that something is wrong with the regEx in both codes, VS code highlight them "red"  here [aie] and here (a)|(i)|(e)...

Comment: What is the test? Are there any errors? What does vscode say?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace -> split -> reverse -> join

```
var x = "1addiiidfa"
var res = x.replace(/[aie]+/g,"V").split('').reverse().join('')
console.log(res)
```